# How to disable Outlook Signature sync across devices

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, email-signature

Our company has a generic email account for Support@OurEmail.com, and we all have our own signatures so the recipient knows who they are dealing with from the Support team.

A Windows Update to my company's Desktop version of Outlook in the past few weeks has introduced syncing of our signatures across all our devices. Is there a setting that can disable this syncing? I tried the following setting on all devices, which has not worked as expected.

[image: Outlook settings applied]

The only other solution I have found suggests editing the registry, but I am reluctant to do this across the company as there must be a better solution. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365/turn-off-signature-synchronize-outlook/m-p/3685421

Comment: I have the same problem and tried  the DisableRoamingSignaturesTemporaryToggle  registry, which did not solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks Philippe, I have tried the same with no luck over the past few months.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that your users are not using roaming profiles.
You may find information about roaming profiles in the article
[All You Need to Know About Roaming Outlook Profiles and OST](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/all-you-need-know-roaming-outlook-profiles-ost-stellardatarecovery?trk=organization-update-content_share-article).

To disable in Group Policy :

- Run `gpedit.msc`
- Navigate to:
  `Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\User Profiles`
- Enable the following policies :

  - "Only allow local user profiles"
  - "Prevent Roaming Profile Changes from propagating to the server".

This will disable roaming profiles on this computer.
A domain administrator can propagate this policy change to all the
domain computers.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my research, I didn't find an organization-level option to disable this feature. I'm afraid that you'll have to disable it by GPO.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer.

Comment: if you have any documentation on how to disable it by GPO that you know works I would like to take a look.

Comment: Just try the steps as harrymc mentioned.